# Haskell - Filtering Odds in function that shows powers of 2

Tags: haskell

I have this developed function that shows the powers of 2 from the range you choose:

```
import Data.Bits(Bits, (.&.))
isPower2 :: (Bits i, Integral i) => i -> Bool
isPower2 n = n .&. (n-1) == 0
```

This works well but i need to filter only the powers of 2 from  odds numbers of the range choosed, for example :

```
filter isPower2 [0 .. 1000]
[0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512]
```

This input and output above shows all the powers between 0 and 1000 but what i need is only the powers from odds, so my output that i need is:

```
[2,8,32,128,512]
```

Is there a way to filter this function pointing only to odds numbers? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend first writing a function that checks whether a power of two is odd power of two.

```
power2isOddPower2 :: (Bits i, Integral i) => i -> Bool
```

Maybe first think how to do this for the concrete case `Word8`, then generalize it to arbitrary positive integers.

Then you can combine this to a predicate that checks whether an arbitrary number is an odd power of two, and use that for the filtering:

```
filter (\n -> isPower2 n && power2isOddPower2 n) [0 .. 1000]
```

Comment: I add to what i developed that function that checks whether a power of two is odd (power2isOddPower2 :: (Bits i, Integral i) => i -> Bool) but i get an error, is simply adding to the code that function? Thanks

Comment: @JohnJackson58 to get help with that error you'll need to show your attempt and what the error is.

Comment: Sorry, when i add that function below my code i get error "The type signature for 'power2isOddPower2' lacks an accompanying binding" , "Failed, no modules loaded"

Comment: So you didn't write _any_ implementation. How could it _possibly_ work then??

Comment: How could i implement a function that i already has wrote above? is the same function i wrote with the name changed "power2isOddPower2 "....

Comment: No, it's a different function that does the thing I describe it should do.

Comment: Please copy both functions one below the other and tell me if its a different function or the same with other name.

Answer (score 1):

That's a clever algorithm for checking whether a number is a power of 2. But unfortunately, it's not well suited to this kind of further analysis. So I'm going to propose a slightly different technique. Let's split the problem into pieces. Haskell has a power function called [`(^)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-94-) (actually, it has three that are subtly different, but for our purposes the simplest one will do just fine). So let's start by getting *all* of the powers of two. Yes, all of them.

```
> map (2 ^) [0..]
[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,...]
```

That's an infinite list, which Haskell has no problem with. If you run it in GHCi, you'll need to hit Ctrl+C to stop it from outputting forever.

Now we want to take the ones smaller than some limit.

```
> takeWhile (< 1000) $ map (2 ^) [0..]
[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512]
```

[`takeWhile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile) is a function which, as the name implies, stops once the condition is false. It's like `filter`, but once it encounters *one* false value, it stops completely (`filter` will never terminate on infinite lists, because it insists on checking every value).

So now we have a way to get the list you have in the OP. But we started with the powers (`[0..]`). So if we want to filter some powers, we can add a `filter` to the right-hand side

```
> takeWhile (< 1000) . map (2 ^) . filter (\x -> x `mod` 2 == 1) $ [0..]
[2,8,32,128,512]
```

Of course, we would want to split this into a few helper functions (`isOdd`, for instance, is pretty easy to factor out into a `where` clause), as it's getting a bit long on its own. But that's the basic idea.

Comment: “But unfortunately, it's not well suited to this kind of further analysis.” Not true, it's quite easy to use bitwise operators for the whole task. And though your suggestion is certainly valid for the given example, it is definitely a solution to a different problem than what the OP primarily asked about. Also... why not just `takeWhile (<1000) $ (2^)<$>[1,3..]`?